# Calling REST API with parameter

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a product browser. I wrote simple HTML view code with a text field, button and result list. I also wrote REST API GET method with the parameter which query objects by ID. Url of my view is #/Products but REST method URL #/Products/Id

REST GET

```
@Path("/{id:[0-9][0-9]*}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response findById(@PathParam("id") Long id) {body}.
```

Now I'm trying to write controller to #/Product view

```
 angular.module('searchingPage').controller('SearchProductsController', function($scope, $http, $filter, ProductResource ) {

 $scope.search={};
 $scope.performSearchById = function() {
//goal $scope.searchResults = ProductResource.findById($scope.search.id);

    };
})
```

How can I call my REST API with parameter and right path with Id in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the '#' sign use for client side not server side, your rest method url is probably something like *"api/Products/Id"*. you can simply call rest method as below

```
$scope.performSearchById = function() {

    $http({
    url: 'api/Products/' + $scope.search.id,
    method: 'GET'
    }).then(function(data){
            $scope.searchResults = data.data;
           })
    };
}
```